# Slide left or right to reveal timestamp

Tags: swift, collections, uicollectionview, timestamp, messagekit

i'm trying to implement  slide to show timestamp into messengekit libaray

One thing I am stuck on is how to "Slide" the entire collection view to show the timestamp of each message. That said, I don't expect the algorithm for the timestamps, I already have the timestamps stored for each message. I'm only confused on the concept of sliding the collection view. I can't find anything on it. I've tried plenty of documentation. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Currently the library doesn't support this functionality and nor is it an easy feature to accomplish. We don't have something like this planned for the best future

Comment: https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/issues/718

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to achieve this with MessageKit.

```
        self.showMessageTimestampOnSwipeLeft = true
```

```
    func messageTimestampLabelAttributedText(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let messageDate = message.sentDate
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        let dateString = formatter.string(from: messageDate)
        return
            NSAttributedString(string: dateString, attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)])
    }
```